# How to get access to local stored session cookies?

Tags: java, http, session, post, cookies

When I enter some websites, I can see requests with session cookies.
How can I get access to these values, without sending any requests from Java code?

Comment: Can you add more details? How do you "*enter some websites*" and "*can see requests with session cookies*"? Which values would you like to access precisely?

Comment: http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html

Comment: I'm opening site via web browser and reading requests in browser debugging tool. I need to get cookies stored on my PC, which are sent with request. I would like to know where such cookies are located.

Answer (score 0):

cookies were saved in our compute.Different browsers stored it in different place.such as IE located in `C:\Users\ying\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache`,you can search about other browsers's cookies by google.

Comment: I'm using IE but I don't have such directory (hidden files visible). Also, I think that session cookie isn't stored on hard drive but only in RAM. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you need change "ying" into your account name of computer.open your IE, open tools ,you will find "internet options".open it ,you will find "settings".open it ,you will find "current location" .you need open "view files" , this path has many files.cookies were save here.